# How to Properly use CuPy Streams

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use CuPy streams effectively.  The following code calculates a matrix power via repeated matrix multiplication.  I would expect the following code to spend most of its time at the synchronize line, but it seems to spend most of its time in the matmul lines.  Is this a bug in CuPy, or am I mis-using the CuPy stream?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
stream_example.py
Inefficiently calculates a matrix power through repeated matrix multiplication.  
"""

import numpy as np
import cupy
import sys
import time

def main(N, power):
    compute_stream = cupy.cuda.stream.Stream(non_blocking=True)

    with compute_stream:
        d_mat = cupy.random.randn(N*N, dtype=cupy.float64).reshape(N, N)
        d_ret = d_mat

        cupy.matmul(d_ret, d_mat)

        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(power - 1):
            d_ret = cupy.matmul(d_ret, d_mat)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Time spent on cupy.matmul for loop: {end_time - start_time}")

        start_time = time.time()
        compute_stream.synchronize()
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Time spent compute_stream.synchronize(): {end_time - start_time}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

The results show that most of the time is spent within the repeated multiplication for loop rather than stream.synchronize().  Can cupy.matmul() not be used asynchronously?

```
$ python3 stream_example.py 16384 1024
Time spent on cupy.matmul for loop: 2.667935609817505
Time spent compute_stream.synchronize(): 4.2438507080078125e-05
```

Comment: The issue is that the `with` construct is not causing the `matmul` operations to be issued on the chosen stream.  Instead they are being issued to the null stream.  (A time of less than 3 seconds is implausible for the given operation - your application is taking much longer than that to complete.)  You can convince yourself of this by converting the stream synchronize to a `cupy.cuda.Device().synchronize()`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like adding the following works around this issue.  I'll reserve the green checkmark for someone who can come up with a less hacky solution:

```
import cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cublas
from cupy.cuda import device
handle = device.get_cublas_handle()
...
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cublas.setStream(handle, compute_stream.ptr)
```

```
$ python3 stream_example.py 16384 4
Time spent on cupy.matmul for loop: 0.007548093795776367
Time spent compute_stream.synchronize(): 5.099333047866821
```

Comment: For some reason this workaround seems to take significantly longer to run as well?

Comment: It's taking longer to run because you weren't measuring execution time properly with the previous run. The `matmul` launches are/were still asynchronous.  so ~3s was not a valid time for the previous case.

Comment: That makes sense.  I thought it was a slurm issue causing the hanging.  I'm probably just synchronizing the wrong stream.

Comment: By [my read of things](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/master/examples/stream/cublas.py) you appear to be doing it correctly (in your original posting).  It looks to me like cupy is behaving in an unexpected fashion.  Possibly worthy of a cupy issue.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I'll take the conversation over to: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/4199

Comment: To save future readers a few clicks, this appears to have tripped over a "known" issue in `cupy` which should be fixed in `cupy 8.1`

Answer (score 1):

You can't benchmark your code like that. Cupy does all sorts of stuff under the hood that can muddle your measurements. You need to use the cupy profiler, see: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/performance.html#benchmarking

I'm guessing your code is doing the actual synchronize after the measurement of the end_time after the call to synchronize, because that call only schedules a synchronize on the current cuda stream without actually executing it.